# Limit number of running threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have inherited some code below that works fine, the only problem is, I want to be able to limit the number of threads that run at any one time, at the moment I have around 8-10 jobs that run in parallel, I want to limit the number of threads to maybe 3 or 4 at any time, is this possible with the code below without too many changes?

```
Public Sub threading_Example()

 Dim threadList As New List(Of Thread)

 For n = 0 To numJobs 'about 8-10 normally

     Dim new_job As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf do_Job))
     Dim job As New Job

     'job.stuff = stuff

     newJob.Start(job)
     threadList.Add(new_job)

 Next

 For Each t As Thread In threadList
     t.Join()
 Next

End Sub

Public Sub do_Job(ByVal job As Object)
   'do task 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) for example:

```
ReadOnly Sem As New Semaphore(3, 4)

    Sub Main()

        Dim threadList As New List(Of Thread)
        Dim numJobs As Integer
        For n = 0 To numJobs

            Dim new_job As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf do_Job))

            new_job.Start()
            threadList.Add(new_job)

        Next

        For Each t As Thread In threadList
            t.Join()
        Next


    End Sub


    Public Sub do_Job(ByVal job As Object)

        Sem.WaitOne()
        'only 3 or 4 threads at time can do task
        Sem.Release()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Thread Pool. Thread Pool has many optimizations built into it. e.g. Thread Pool can determine the number of cores the machine has and will schedule number of threads accordingly. If there are more number of threads created but not getting utilized properly, Thread Pool will kill additional threads.

Consider refactoring the code with Thread Pool. Thread Pool also has the option of limiting the number of threads (this is however not recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the ThreadPool instead. You can limit the number of threads it uses with the SetMin|MaxThreads methods.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you use, you might also simply try this:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, 
            (New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4}), 
             Sub(i As Integer)
                ' do job        
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                Debug.Print("done no. {0}", i)
             End Sub)
```

No need for a Tasklist and joining the threads